# How to make a weekly email report in GA4

Tags: google-analytics-4

I have a new website and want to use the new Google Analytics 4.

But what I don't find is how I can make a weekly email report with data such as how many visitors, top 10 pageview, used browsers, screen sizes etc etc ..... ;-)

In the old GA or Matomo is this no problem but call me stupid but I can't find anything in GA, even the Help section doesn't help me here.

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Not possible yet. Hopefully functionality should arrive soon

Comment: please back this up with the source

Comment: No Source really available other than this:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9317657?hl=en

Where Google advocates using Looker studio connection to create shareable reports.  But it is a missed feature - hence my hoping it would arrive soon.